# How to Stay Signed In in a Mobile App using Microsoft OAuth?

Tags: mobile, office365, nativescript, access-token

I am working on an app using NativeScript and am using Microsoft OAuth2 to authenticate the user, send emails and access SharePoint with it. My problem is that the authentication token I get expires after 1 hour so the user has to login again over and over. A temporary solution I am using is refresh_token which lasts longer (I believe 14 days by default and up to 90 days) but still that is not what I would like. My ideal solution would be an option to stay signed in but it does not seem to exist at this moment.
I have read this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso and am not sure how to extend the lifetime of my token. If I can extend it at least for a year or six months, that would be great but I don't know how to do it. 
My app is not registered in Azure but in apps.dev.microsoft.com and I have looked in the manifest but haven't found anything I could write to change the token type or its lifetime.

Comment: you can't stay signed in in oAuth spec unless you increase the lifetime of token. But hey there is refresh token, just request a new token everytime the token expires using refresh token

Comment: Thanks @DotNetDreamer for your answer. Yes, I am using the refresh token but I wanted to know if there is a way.. even if it's not using oAuth.. The refresh token also has an expiration and mine I believe is 14 days and in the website it says it can go up to 3 months but I don't know how to configure that.

Comment: you don't have to worry about that. When you request a token using refreshtoken, then simply replace the new token with your existing token in local storage and use that new token. This way the timming of the new token and its refresh token will be re-set and this cycle will continues and the user will never logout

Comment: hmm.. that's interesting. I did not know this could happen. I will try that. Thank you, @DotNetDreamer